# Unable to upload *.ncb files to RTC

Tags: vb.net, visual-c++, rational-team-concert

I am migrating the `vb.net` project to RTC but the problem here is there is onle file with extension `x.ncb` and RTC is not allowing to upload.

Now my issue here is I am unable to understand whether this file is not allowed in RTC?

Can this be removed and uploaded to RTC?

Comment: By not allowed, do you mean you see an error message? If yes, which one? And which version of RTC  are you using? 4.x? 5.x?

Comment: An .ncb file is the C++ Intellisense database for old VS versions.  VS would have a lock on the file.  If that's accurate at all then, no, uploading it makes no sense.  Use files for testing that resemble what your user will use, not whatever you've got lying around in your own project directory.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your response.... Actually project was developed few years before and I am new to it and don't have expertise on language. As per your input I understood that file will be used for testing in this case can file be deleted and if deletion is not possible how can I proceed with the migrating to RTC.

Comment: @VonC Thanks for your reply... I got the error as `Error 400 with text as Bad Request` and I am not sure what is the error and coming to the version of RTC I am using `3.0.1.1`. Does version will have any7 effect on the file upload?

Comment: If you have bad request, I would recommend you looking if your connection settings are valid in VS client. You can enable trace according to https://jazz.net/wiki/bin/view/Deployment/IntegrationsTroubleshootingDebugRTCVSClientVerbose to see what is exactly the error.

Comment: @kazik1616 Thanks for your reply... Actually I am not using any VS client I am just uploading the already developed application to Rational Team Concert

Comment: @HansPassant sir can you please provide your views on my issue.. thanks

Comment: I would like to clarify then what kind of client do you use. Do you use RTC Eclipse client? Or rather command line client?

Comment: @kazik1616 yes its an RTC Eclipse client.

Comment: OK. So see what is entire error message in your .log file (including stack trace). It might be valueble here.